# Sending Sensitive Information via Cookies

Tags: express, cookies

I am currently going through a flow for inviting an administrator to my website and was wondering what are some good and secure ways (possibly using cookies) to send sensitive information to my server (or retrieve it by my browser).

At the moment an administrator receives an invitation, a code is attached to that invitation that lets us gather more information about the invitee and also create a state that we can use to verify.

In my Express app, I do something similar to the following:

`res.redirect(configuration.siteUri + '/administrators/' + response.code);`

Instead of having this `response.code` directly inside of the URL, I would instead like to send it via a cookie server side, and then retrieve it later on when I need to during this process.

I'm thinking of creating a route on my API that I can call to retrieve this code. I've read a bit about cookies and it seems like at least the two options I'd like to have set would be `HttpOnly` and `Secure`.

Are there any other ways of making this information more secure? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to secure it is to encrypt the cookie data into some kind of encoded string that can't be read . In order to do that you must use a hashing algorithm . Below link is lynda course spoke about encrypt/decrypt cookies data .

[Encrypting cookies](https://www.lynda.com/PHP-tutorials/Encrypting-cookies/133321/180309-4.html)